# java- how to extract words and files into a set?

Tags: java

I am working on creating a simple algorithm in Java that would extract words from a database table along with their respectively file and keep it in a set or array.

For example, this is how my table looks like:

```
path        word
file1        w1

file1        w2


file1        w3

.........

file2        w2

file2        w5

.........
```

and the list goes on and on.

And in my program, I would like to extract these data from the table so it stores in a set like this:

```
w1={file1}
w2={file1, file2}
w3={file1}
w5={file2}
...... and etc
```

Of course there will definitely be more data in the table but this is just the general idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

The first step I would do I establish a JDBC connection to my database and run a select statement from my table. However, I can't figure how I would extract them in a way that would store them like how I described above.

Should I use an array or hashSet or something else?

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: data structure like `HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> h = new HashMap<>();` will work.

Comment: @pwxcoo And just insert everything into the hashmap?

Comment: @Daredevil yep, iterate list, and use key to store `word`, use value to store `{file1, file2}`.

Comment: HashSet is not the best option, if what you want is integrity.. TreeSet is duplicate-free and HashMap is more efficient when retrieving the data through the key, that can be the path.

Comment: But how would I extract them and make sure each word is tied to a file so if another same word exist in a diff file, then it would insert to same key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashMap<String,TreeSet<String>> map = new HashMap<>();`

Then your code will be:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT PATH, WORD FROM TABLE_A");

while(rs.next()) {
    if (map.containsKey(rs.getString("WORD"))) { // If the word is already in your hash map
        TreeSet<String> path = map.get(rs.getString("WORD")); //get the set of files where this word exist 
        path.add(rs.getString("PATH")); // add the new path to the set
        map.put(rs.getString("WORD"), path); // update the map
    } else { // else if the word is new
        TreeSet<String> path = new TreeSet<String>(); // create a new set
        path.add(rs.getString("PATH")); // add the path to the set
        map.put(rs.getString("WORD"), path); // add the new data to the map
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you mix hashmap and treeset? A hashmap would suffice?

Comment: ```HashMap``` is used to take note of the list of the ```words```, while ```TreeSet``` will take note of the list of the ```path``` that that word exist.

Comment: I see. In this case, shouldn't my word be the "key" instead of value?

Comment: In my answer your ```word``` is the key

Comment: I don't think i'll create a function just to retrive data from table, I'll just directly made a preparedStatement in my main method to extract, how would your solution look like?

Comment: Because the moment i extracted from the table, it should straight insert into the hashmap/treeSet created.

Answer (score 1):

**TreeSet** is better than **HashMap** in this case, cause it don't accept duplicated values, consequently guarantees more integrity.

Anyways, **HashMap** fits better to your needs, cause *Path* can be the key and *word* the value.

I prepared a example of how you can retrieve *path* and *word* then put them into the *key* and *value* of a HashMap, respectively:

```
Map<String, String> fileParameters = new HashMap<>();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT path, word FROM files");
while(rs.next()) {
String path = rs.getString("path");
String name = rs.getString("word");
fileParameters.put(path, name);
```

Comment: Yea because in my case, there could be have duplicated values such as w1={f1} and w5={f1}

Comment: Understood, but the data structure your'e using (path/word) is analogous to key/value pairs of a map implementation.. considering keys are paths and each one are unique representation of files, HashMap appears to be the best option. This way we still can have duplicated file names

Comment: So you are saying it should be word=key and path=values right?

Comment: No, path=key, cause each path represents a unique file, and word=value cause words can be duplicated :)

Comment: Here the ```path``` is the key, but I think the OP needs to have the ```word``` as the key since the OP needs to know where those ```word``` can be found, thus with this example finding that ```path``` needs more work/processing

Comment: Yea i agree with Mark, word=key should be better because there shouldn't be duplicated word in a sense that if there is a duplicated word with different file name, it should insert into the same key row with it's filename

Comment: The question does not specify how the path is composed, so I was considering that path was a full qualified name (path + file name)